# Save sql file without NULL values

Tags: postgresql, null, pg-dump

When I run

```
pg_dump -O --column-inserts -U root map --file=
```

anything that has the value `NULL` is also printed. 
Can I create an SQL file such that the columns which have `NULL` are not included?

`--column-inserts` does create a query which published column name and data.

**Example:**

Say I have a table

```
Name | class | element | Id

Nee     V       NULL      102
Mat     VI      NULL      103
...
```

When I export the sql file 
the data insertion lines look like

```
INSERT INTO table (Name, class, element, Id) VALUES ('Nee', 'V', NULL, 102);
```

what I would like is

```
INSERT INTO table (Name, class, Id) VALUES ('Nee', 'V', 102);
```

Such that the sql file doesn't contain any NULL element to be put into the database. 
This is required because in the system database, we use a lot of columns and my code only changes a few of them. Hence the sql generator has a LOT of NULLs.

Comment: Please clarify what you want with a short example what the data should look like *exactly*. And check your last sentence for typos. Doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Why do you care about `NULL` values being in there?

Comment: Well this table is being used by other people along with a robot. They had difficulty changing the database details fast and run sql to get everything upto date

Comment: You are aware that an INSERT with an explicit NULL is *different* from an INSERT omitting the column if a column default is in place? The default kicks in in the second case. This may or may not be relevant, depending on how you restore the data and on whether you have any non-null column defaults. Typically, it *is* relevant, since column defaults are restored before data is reloaded.

Comment: There's no option to make `pg_dump` do what you want. You'd have to write custom code to output the INSERTs with only the desired columns.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't find anything either. I'll just leave it with --column-inserts. Thanks a lot for all your help !

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no option.  Secondly the inserts don't look like that which makes it more or less impossible to automatically process the dump to do what you want.

pg_dump creates inserts by default with an implicit column list, i.e.:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('test2 test', 'foobar');
```

This is ok, because it uses the columns in the order specified in the table declaration.  However, it also means you can't omit columns.  So this isn't something you can quickly do with sed in an automatic fashion.

Determining a proper solution here depends on what problem exactly you are trying to solve.  In the absence of a problem to solve, the best I can say is "don't even try to do this."  There are likely better solutions for your problem.